# Online store architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, integration

In our company 2 development teams:

1. Web team developing online store
2. java team developing CRM application

Online store send REST requests to CRM. And Java team lead asked web team lead to restrict RPS from online store to CRM, because CRM receive too many requests and periodically goes down. The web team doesn't like it, they think that it is CRM side issue.

1. What is best practice for this kind of situation?
2. Can you provide me reference to some authoritative knowledge base?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best practice for that kind of situation because everything depends on specific circumstances. If the store generates more requests than it is necessary, it should be reduced. If the CRM app cannot handle the required number of requests, it should be optimized (or resources increased). You provided too few details to give you a clear answer.

From the technical side, I can only give you 2 overall suggestions:

- If query requests (GET) cause the problem, you should think of a better data caching on the store side to reduce the number of requests.
- If command requests (POST, PUT etc.) cause the problem, you may consider how many of your requests have to be handled synchronously. Maybe queuing commands instead of processing them right away would help you to better utilize resources of the CRM app and reduce downtime.

I highly doubt if anyone will be able to give you a more concrete answer basing on so limited data.